# Is it possible to download corodava jar version greater 3.5

Tags: android, cordova

I have corodava.js version of 2.9 in my app but google send a alert to update the corodava version due to security issues. I had searched latest version but all the latest version are available with node.js CLI . I hardly want a corodava jar alone .Is the phonegap corodava version is available ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You can download the cordova android source code from here:
https://www.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/cordova-android-3.6.4.tgz

Then uncompress it, go to cordova-android-3.6.4\package\framework in a terminal or cmd
write this command:

```
android update project -p .
```

when it finish write this one

```
ant
```

That should build a cordova-3.6.4.jar

But if you are using plugins right now, cordova 3.X.X doesn't include them, you will have to include them using plugman.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute this in your project folder:

```
cordova platform update android
```

This will upgrade to the last cordova version, that fixes these security issues.

I recommend to remove & add android platform to have a clean android project:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform update android
cordova platform add android
```

Note: This is only for Cordova 3.x users..., From Cordova 2.x it is needed to install Cordova.

Comment: I don't think that works if you are in any version previous to 3.X.X, and the OP have 2.9